# scheme - Show all the pairs of elements which have the greatest common divisor 1

Tags: scheme, racket

I started with the algortihm for combinations but when m will become 0 in the recursion, the first y will be '(()) so the program will show only () which will repeat 4*the size of the list times.

```
(define (pairs-GCD L)
 (define (comb m lst)
  (cond ((= m 0) '(()))
    ((null? lst) '())
    (else (append (map (lambda (y) (cond (equal? (GCD(car lst) y) 1) (cons (car lst) y))) (comb (- m 1) (cdr lst))) (comb m (cdr lst))))))
 (comb 2 L)
```

)
EDIT: Corrected output
Input: '(2 5 3 6 11 15)
Output: '((2 5) (2 3) (2 11) (2 15) (5 3) (5 6) (5 11) (6 11) (3 11) (6 11) (11 15))

Comment: Can you provide a sample input with expected output?

Comment: Just added some input and the expected output

Comment: Hmmm, that's not the `lcm`, looks more like the `gcd`. Also, why `(2 15)` and `(11 15)` are not included in the output?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that... made the gcd but named it wrong. Could have actually made gcd and put for example 15 as the wanted gcd, but anyway this is not the problem. The problem is how can I put the condition so it will return the result.

Comment: Solved it ;) please update the question to indicate that it's GCD you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to do if we use Racket's built-in procedures - we can easily generate all 2-element combinations, test them for the given condition and output a list with the correct pairs:

```
(define (pairs-gcd lst)
  (for/list ([pair (in-combinations lst 2)]
             #:when (= (apply gcd pair) 1))
    pair))
```

For example:

```
(pairs-gcd '(2 5 3 6 11 15))
=> '((2 5) (2 3) (5 3) (5 6) (2 11) (5 11) (3 11) (6 11) (2 15) (11 15))
```

Comment: And if I want to show the result as '((2 . 5) (2 . 3) ....(11 . 15)) what should I modify?

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of the last pair. I wrote (cons (car pair) (cadr pair))

Comment: In Racket, it's nicer to write: (cons (first pair) (second pair))